# How to persist checkboxes with search in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I have a search box and group of check boxes as shown below:

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Category" [(ngModel)] = "searchTerm" (ngModelChange) = "search(searchTerm)">
      <div *ngFor="let data of labels">
            <input type="checkbox" (change)="onSelect(data.id, $event.target.checked)">
            {{data.name}}
      </div>
```

And I have `onSelect` and search function as shown below in my ts file:

```ts
onSelect(data: string, isChecked: boolean) {
  this.selectedArray = <FormArray>this.Form.controls.selected;

  if(isChecked) {
    this.selectedArray.push(new FormControl(data));
  } else {
    let index = this.selectedArray.controls.findIndex(x => x.value == data)
    this.selectedArray.removeAt(index);
    }
  }

  search(searchterm): void {
    this.data = this.dataCopy.filter(function(tag) {
      return tag.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchterm) >= 0;
    });
  }
```

Now the issue that I am facing is when I check the checkbox and search for the term that doesn't exist and then clearing the search term. On doing so, the checkbox that I have checked does not persist its state.

**EDITED:**
Cloned app https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ck8uvj. Now If i check test and then I search m keyword. And again i cleared my search box. The checkbox that I have checked is not persisted.

Comment: Can you replicate it here https://stackblitz.com/ ?

Comment: Yes sure. I will do that.

Comment: @Afsar I have cloned my app. Check edited section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must to use two variables: "labels" and "labelsShow"

Make your "labels" have a property checked

```
labels = [
    {id: 1, name: "Test",checked:false},
    {id: 2, name: "Testing",checked:false}
  ];
```

change the (change) function

```
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="data.checked"
       (change)="data.checked=$event.target.checked">
       {{data.name}}
```

Change search function

```
search(searchterm): void {
    this.labelsShow=this.lables.filter(function(tag) {
      return tag.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchterm) >= 0;
    });
```

Add in ngOnInit a call to seach

```
this.search("")
```

And iterate over labelsShow

```
<div *ngFor="let data of labelsShow">
     ...
</div>
```

You can ask about how work, if I change "labelsShow", there are a change in "labels". This is because labelsShow copy by reference. You can see in action adding in html

```
<p>
{{labelsShow|json}}
</p>
{{labels|json}}
```

::glups:: is almost the same answer that Pengyy

Comment: But I need `onSelect()` function right? Because I want to keep track of all selected checkboxes.

Comment: You have in labels all the labels (checked or not). In any time you can use selectedLabels=labels.filter(x=>x.checked==true) or selectedLabels=labelsShow.filter(x=>x.checked==true). I supouse you want it in a click button or whatever. You needn't a Form

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to save `checked` status of each checkbox along with it's data.

```
<div *ngFor="let data of labels_display">
  <input type="checkbox" (change)="onSelect(data.id, $event.target.checked)" [checked]="data.checked">
  {{data.name}}
</div>


labels = [
  {id: 1, name: "Test", checked: false},
  {id: 2, name: "Testing", checked: false}
];
```

Then, you need to **synchronous** data between `labels_display`(used for display) and `labels`(original data)

```
onSelect(data: number, isChecked: boolean) {
  ...

  // keep sync between labels and labels_display
  const item = this.labels.find(item => item.id === data);
  item.checked = isChecked;
}
```

See fixed **[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rexviu?file=app/app.component.ts)**.